# Determining weights for fitting non-uniformly spaced measured data

Tags: regression, weighted-regression, weights

I have a system of generally known behavior, and some non-uniform measurements of that behavior (let's say without measurement error).  Now I want to fit a simple function to a subset of the measurements.  For the segment shown, this approximation should be a straight, horizontal line.  But a least squares fit with equal weights produces a sloping line, as shown.

[image]

I would like to compute weights for the data points based on their distribution along the x axis.  How can I do this for a small number of data points, say a dozen or less.

Comment: Why do this when the system has "known behavior"?  Could you explain the purpose of this exercise?

Comment: The equation for a straight horizontal line is "y = a", so could you use the mean y value of the data points as the fit?

Comment: @whuber The problem is an artificial one that hopefully illustrates a situation where computing weights would be useful.  "generally known behavior" could be "v-shape".

Comment: @JamesPhillips Actually the mean of these data points is not the mean of the system behavior over this interval.  I would need the weights for that too.

Comment: Artificial or not, it's unclear what you know, what you assume, and what you really want to accomplish.  For instance, exactly what form does your "known behavior" take? Do you know the location of the vertex?  The slopes of the two arms?  The height of graph?  What's the point of fitting a horizontal line (representing a constant response) when the known behavior is decidedly non-constant?  Will the data adhere as closely to the "known behavior" curve as depicted in the plot?

Comment: @whuber Ok, clearly I didn't succeed with the design of my problem for the purpose of the question.  Is it possible to think about the calculation of weights without answers to all those questions?

Comment: I fear that different answers based on different interpretations might appear: that's why it's important to make your question as clear and specific as you can.

Comment: I'd be happy with multiple answers!

Comment: Ok, I posted a new question which hopefully works better.